# get profile picture with exact height and width with facebook api

Tags: php, image, facebook-graph-api

I am new bie to facebook APIs.

I am using PHP SDK version 3.2.3.

Below is the api call

```
$myApi="/me?fields=email,id,name,picture.height(600).width(590),friends.limit(10).fields(name,picture.width(180).height(120))";

$customizedUser=$facebook->api($myApi);
```

The image I am getting in `$customizedUser['picture']['data']['url']` is of 708 x 720 pixels.

Exact requirement is of 590 x 600 pixel image only.

What is the exact relations/mappings that we should keep in mind while providing custom height and width ??

Is it possible to get image with exact required dimensions ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want single user's pic at once you could try, https://graph.facebook.com/rb.dhoriya/picture?width=590&height=600

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/picture?width=590&height=600`